# How to report ROS 1 wiki issue?

Tags: debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Step 1.3 in the installation procedure at https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Debian fails, apparently because the key server at `ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net` is offline:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.b7Cz6OV1QZ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

(edit): I resolved the issue by doing this instead:

```
sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

My *real* questions is: how do I file an issue (and possibly contribute) for this? There doesn't appear to be a link on that wiki page for submitting doc error reports.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400536/how-to-report-ros-1-wiki-issue?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2022-05-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-12**:
As you wrote:

> My real questions is: how do I file an issue (and possibly contribute) for this?

I've updated the title of your post.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-12**:
And a related / duplicate question: #q222114.

Summarising: as the ROS 1 wiki is a wiki, the typical procedure would be to register for an account and fix the page you believe needs fixing.

The key server being down / flaky has been a problem before (see [ros-infrastructure/roswiki#140](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/140) for a (really) old ticket about it, and #q223702 for (one) previous Q&A about it).

I remember @tfoote dealing with something similar recently, but can't find it.

Perhaps he can provide some input.

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2022-05-13**:
Thanks, I finally noticed the "login" link at the bottom of the wiki page. I'll give that a shot. TBH, I'm a little reluctant to offer advice on a page that's so fundamental. I'm sure there are security implications here that I don't fully understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own question: instructions for editing a ROS wiki page found here: http://wiki.ros.org/EditingTheWiki#How_to_Edit_a_ROS_Wiki_Page

P.S. Following gvdhoorn's advice (above), I updated the Debian installation instructions with the keyserver that worked for me, as of May 2022: hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80.

---

Originally posted by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) with karma: 567 on 2022-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-30**:
Please also set your own answer as correct by clicking on the grey check mark to the left.